# Node API - Exception Details: 4 parse_error_exception: Parse Erro

Tags: wallet, rpc, api, node

I just used node api to access the keosd for wallet lock.

But I've got the following error..

```
2018-11-12T08:52:24.874 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:474    
   handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 4 parse_error_exception: Parse Error

Unexpected char '100' in "default"

{"c":100,"s":"default"}

thread-0  json.cpp:437 variant_from_stream

{"str":"default"}

thread-0  json.cpp:460 from_string
```

What would be wrong?

I also tested in the following site.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.1.0/reference#wallet_lock

Same error..

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by using the following node.js code. 
The problem was due to the quotation mark in the message body..

body:"default"  =>  body:"\"default\""

==================

var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',

url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8899/v1/wallet/lock',

headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },

body:"\"default\""

};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {

if (error) throw new Error(error);

console.log(body);

});

Answer (score 0):

**This will work too**

> var request = require("request");
>
> var options = { method: 'POST',   url:
>   'http://127.0.0.1:9999/v1/wallet/lock',   headers:     {
>   'cache-control': 'no-cache',
>        'Content-Type': 'application/json' },   body: 'default',   json: true };
>
> request(options, function (error, response, body) {   if (error) throw
>   new Error(error);
>
> console.log(body); });